# Change two childs from Java code

Tags: android, eclipse, drag-and-drop, imageview

I am gonna explain my problem as well as I can.

I have two **linear layout**. Each one has an **imageview**.

I am playing with Drag & Drop propierties. One imageview (A) has an **onTouchListener** and another one (B) has an **onDragListener**.

When I drop the View A into the View B I execute this code:

```
 public boolean onDrag(View imagen_blanca, DragEvent dragEvent) {
    int dragAction = dragEvent.getAction();

   if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
     switch (dragEvent.getAction()){
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
             break;
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
             break;
         case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
             View imagen_desplazada = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
             ViewGroup papa_blanca = (ViewGroup) imagen_blanca.getParent();
             ViewGroup papa_desplazada = (ViewGroup) imagen_desplazada.getParent();
             papa_blanca.removeView(imagen_blanca);
             papa_desplazada.removeView(imagen_desplazada);
             papa_blanca.addView(imagen_desplazada);
             papa_desplazada.addView(imagen_blanca);
             imagen_desplazada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             break;
    }
}
    return true;
}
```

**What do I try to do?**
I get two Linear Layout (papa_blanca and papa_desplazada) who hold an imageview each one.
I remove his child from each one.
I add a new child.

It works when I move once. I mean: when I drop A on B they change his father.

My problem comes here. When I try to move again A on B to get the original position that errors come:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works! Error was in another prt of my code